# Site I manage does not get good ranking in Google

Tags: seo

A site I just started to manage is not banned in Google because I can find the domain in the index, but it gets extremely poor ranking -- almost nowhere to be found.

Does anyone know of a good method for determining how and/or why a site gets a poor ranking in Google. The site I have has been around for a while and is very rich with content relative to "youth sports". Yet you can hardly find it in the Google.

Sorry for asking this question here, but if you have ever posted anything to the Google Help and User forums you;ll find you get no responses or assistance. SO is the only place I can ever get exceptional and timely help.

Comment: SEO and search engine ranking questions belong at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry John...thanks for the negative vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. Someone else did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell for sure as no one knows exactly how pages are ranked. However, we do have a pretty good idea of what many of the ranking factors are so we can be sure do them to help our chances of ranking well. [This question at Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google) is a good start. [So is this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/seo-how-to-separate-fact-from-fiction/13007#13007). Once you're sure you got the basics down you need to promote your website in the hopes of getting quality links to your pages. But if you don't have quality content (and what you call quality content may not be what Google and others call quantity content) you're not going to stand much of a chance of ranking well.

Comment: Ok, good stuff. Thanks John. Do you (or do any other readers) know if there is a difference between being "banned" from Google and being 'blacklisted"? Would they be one and the same?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any dirty tricks like white text on white background to contain some false keywords etc.? Google continually discovers these tricks and penalizes them. Cheating doesn't pay off. I don't tell this is your case, but I just want to warn against it, in general.